# Relay SMS to a normal computer

Tags: sms

Is anyone aware of a way to relay SMS messages back and forth to a PC/laptop?  As in, so you could deal with texting on the computer and leave the phone sitting around wherever on the same LAN.  Any target OS is fine.

I've searched myself for this but it turns out "SMS relay" refers to something slightly different.

Comment: The question "Is there an app..." will be closed because app recommendations are off-topic, and "How to write an app..." will also be closed because programming questions are off-topic. Your best hope here would be to focus on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @onik Thx -- I'll rephrase this.  I'm actually not looking for programming help, that was kind of extraneous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has no such native feature – but there are plenty of apps dealing with exactly this, see my collection to [Send SMS remotely](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid#group_670). The most famous candidates from that list are probably [Pushbullet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android) and [MightyText](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms).

If you want more, there are even apps to (almost) completely remote-control your Droid, see [Manage your Android Device from your Computer](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement). From this category, [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) is one of the favorites.

Comment: @goldilocks:`Any target OS is fine`, besides **Airdroid** as suggested by Izzy, you can try `KDEconnect` app but the functionality is  limited to Android 4.4.x and KDE(Linux). Other than that `Webkey` app from F-Droid works well like Airdroid but requires Rooted Device.

Answer (score 1):

Look at mighty text. It let's you open a website on your computer and send/receive texts.

Answer (score 1):

Google voice provides this capability along with many other useful features.

Answer (score 1):

I use MySMS http://www.mysms.com/.  It works very well.